# Unable to include case owner in Entitlement Process Milestones

Tags: casemilestone, entitlements

I have a requirement to provide customizable timelines to close a case with in specified time.

So, i set up entitlement process but my requirement is to apply milestone for specific cases with specific record owner.If i remove case owner from below criteria it's working fine.But if i include it is not working don't know where i went wrong.

My requirement is simple in Entitlement Process

**Case enters the process**  Based on case created date

**Case exits the process** Only

1.when Case Record Type == Customer Order

2.Status == Shipped,On hold - Future Dated Deployment)

And i have only one Milestone under this entitlement process to complete case within 48 hours. with following criteria

[image]

Comment: Can you provide exact requirement with an example of customizable timelines to close a case with in specified time, probably I can give you some approach

Comment: I updated my entitlement process criteria.Please check my updated answer and let me know if i miss any points

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to include Case owner in Entitlement Process.

Basically Cases will be related to Entitlement record which is linked to one Entitlement Process.

Rather during milestone configuration include case owner as filter criteria.
Secondly, sometimes changing the status doesn't initiate a new milestone, for that scenario, you need to perform asynchronous update on that case record to fire the milestone.

Comment: Thank you but in above approach I include case owner only in milestone criteria but still it is not working. Is there any limitation about using case ownership

Comment: I don't see any limitations,  this kind of requirements I have already done. Basically you want to perform different SLA based on Case owner, is that correct?

Comment: Right now we need to setup one SLA for all cases with record type called customer order created by a user called Orders Team